# How to rotate view relative to a point

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I'm developing an app which has a compass with an arrow on the top of the circle.

---

The problem is that I've tried many ways such as :

```
View Arrow = findViewById(R.id.arrow);
   RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    Arrow.setAnimation(rotateAnim);
    rotateAnim.start();
```

---

But couldn't achieve the result that has been described in the image.
I don't want to rotate circle itself, only the Arrow in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90,
       RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
       RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
```

to this:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90,
       RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
       RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

This assumes that the center of the circle is at the center of the image (so we're using 50%x and 50%y for the pivot points). If the center of the circle is *not* at the center of the image, you'll have to tweak the pivots until you find the right spot.

Answer (score -1):

If arrow is separate view you should simultaneously implement 2 kind of animation:

1) rotation on arrow center from 0 to 90 degrees clockwise;

2) movement arrow along 90-degrees arc path.

Comment: @TarlanAhad :) Your question is "How to rotate view relative to a point" - the answer is "rotate and move". And there are many ways to implement that rotation: you can create custom view, or use `ImageView` with arrow bitmap, or use vector drawable. How to know what implementation you needed?

Comment: As you see there is a problem with my code that's why I shared it as well, if I wanted to get an idea I wouldn't share my code there, Sir